# create compiled version of python source

Tags: python, cron

I have a scraping project and to run the project using command

```
python3 source/index.py
```

index.py is the entry point to scrape the web

Now I need to make cron job on gcp compute engine...

Is this possible to create a cron job without actually putting the source code there, something like compile version of project.

Thanks

Comment: What is the reason for not putting the source code there? Is it to keep the source code private? or is it to simplify deployment?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **pyinstaller** from the *PyPi* repository, which converts your python code to a binary executable and supports multiple platforms.

You can find a simple tutorial
at [https://techmonger.github.io/82/pyinstaller-script-to-binary](https://techmonger.github.io/82/pyinstaller-script-to-binary/). You can also find full documentation [here](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/), which you should read.

To compile full source, try this command

```
pyinstaller --onefile yourEntrySourcecode.py
```

Comment: I have a full project with multiple page, will it compile full source code

Comment: yes , pyinstaller --onefile yourEntrySourcecode.py

Comment: pyinstaller also has a feature to encrypt bytecode:
`pyinstaller --key ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can compile Python scripts to a binary code using various methods, but I have found out that using [`Nuitka`](https://nuitka.net/) is more efficient.

> Nuitka is a Python-to-C++ compiler that supports almost all versions of python. for optimization you can choose the compiler that is going to use for the compilation

*for more information go into the [official documentation](https://nuitka.net/)*

The command syntax is as easy as

```bash
$ nuitka --standalone --recurse-all main.py
```

you can also use [`pyinstaller`](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/) with some options to compile all the project.

```bash
$ pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

But the program compilation is not neccessary in fact crontab can run any shell command in the 6th field separated by `%`.

here are the fields

```
minutes hours week_day(0-6) month command
```

Example cron job that will execute every 2 minutes:

```
2 * * * /usr/bin/python3%/path/to/source/index.py
```

#### Useful links:

- [ibm crontab](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=c-crontab-command)
- [how to compile python script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/324871/how-to-compile-a-python-file)
- [compiling python code](http://web.archive.org/web/20201111220256/http://effbot.org/zone/python-compile.htm)

Comment: +1 for Nuitka. It also makes the compiled binary faster than plain CPython. Don't expect wonders, but it's usually faster